# How do I keep load module dynamically but without constant memory usage increase?

Tags: javascript, v8, deno

There is a need to load and serialize esm module dynamically on deno. As of I know, since there is no way to clear cache on `await import()`, I tried importing inside `WebWorker`, then kill it after it's done.

Profiler tells me that all of the imported source code is piled up inside the worker, but after killing the worker I don't see process' memory usage decline. (checked using `docker status`)

Below is simplified example code.

```
// worker.ts
self.onmessage = async (evt: MessageEvent) => {
  const mod = await import(evt.data);
  self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(mod));
}
```

```
// manager.ts
let worker = new Worker("./worker.ts");

// trying to clear source code piled up
setInterval(() => {
  worker.terimnate();
  worker = new Worker("./worker.ts")
}, 10_000);

worker.onmessage = (evt: MessageEvent) => console.log(e.data);

worker.postMessage('https://deno.land/x/zod@v3.22.4/index.ts')
```

Comment: It's possible the memory is only reclaimed once needed. I suggest filling available memory limits (there should be V8 flags to set to lower it for easier testing too) and then creating/destroying workers to test if memory is reused correctly.

Comment: An alternative to workers is the [subprocess API](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/subprocess) — you'd need to serialize and deserialize your messages. Your example code doesn't demonstrate enough to understand whether it would be an appropriate pattern for your actual case, but using that API would move the responsibility of deallocation to the process host (docker) instead of the JS host (V8).

Comment: Since limiting memory doesn't help eliminating the tendency of memory increment, I decided to make it as scheduled job instead of server.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting hard memory limits, such as

`deno run --v8-flags='--max-heap-size=50,--max-old-space-size=50' \ https://deno.land/std@0.87.0/examples/welcome.ts`